# !MESSAGE Error encountered during update !SUBENTRY 1 com.aptana.js.core

Tags: android, titanium-mobile

I just installed Titanium Studio and checked for all necessary updated.

Help -> Check for updates

Help -> Check for Titanium updates

After running the "Check for Titanium updates" I always get an error message that installation failed and to see the log file for details.

I viewed the Log files to see details...

Help -> Studio -> Log File

I found  the following message:

> !MESSAGE Error encountered during update !SUBENTRY 1
>   com.aptana.js.core 4 0 2013-05-31

Apparently, there is an issue with node.ACS CLI.

> npm ERR! missing: acs@*, required by undefined@undefined  npm

These are the highlights from the "Diagnostics file"

Help -> Studio -> Run Diagnostic Test...

> Host OS: Windows 8 OS Version: 6.2 OS Arch: x86
>
> JRE Version: 1.7.0_21 Titanium Studio Version: 3.1.0.201304151600
>
> Android SDK Version: Google APIs Android 4.2.2 Android NDK Version:
>   Unknown/Uninstalled Latest Titanium SDK: 3.1.0.GA
>
> Titanium SDK Version: 3.1.0 SDK Modules API Version:2 SDK Timestamp:
>   04/15/13 18:45 SDK Build Number: 57634ef
>
> Titanium CLI Version: 3.1.0 Titanium CLI Enabled: true
>
> Node.JS Version: v0.8.22

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a solution for the error.

To correct the issue install the acs manually:

1> Launch the command line as administrator

2> npm install -g acs

I restarted Titanium Studio.

When I run

Help -> Check for updates

Help -> Check for Titanium updates

I am error free on both counts. :)

Hopefully, someone will find this useful.